# Logging of realtime database items (firebase) in flutter stopped midway

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I want my flutter application to read Realtime Database items in firebase, but my console starts printing entries and suddenly stops in the middle (there are more than 30 entries to print). Here are my dart files and output on a console:

```
// single_page.dart

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';


class SinglePageApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SinglePageApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SinglePageAppState createState() => _SinglePageAppState();
}

class _SinglePageAppState extends State<SinglePageApp> {

  DatabaseReference _databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();
  
  void printResults() {
    _databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      printResults();
      return Container();
  }
}
```

```
// main.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import './single_page.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // modified
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SinglePageApp(),
    );
  }
}
```

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
Reloaded 0 libraries in 131ms.
I/chatty  (11266): uid=10154(com.example.firebasetest) 1.ui identical 1 line
I/flutter (11266): Data : {global: 1624522599522, readings: {-Mcx9YIBFKDmt2SG3zgs: {Temperature: 21, Humidity: 38}, -Mcx6NY-dij-Hrpzlxx5: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 39}, -Mcx7RVECF5_Phy-HW4u: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 38}, -Mcx5fF5e5Sv8qt7RwnN: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 39}, -Mcx612cV63T02_kU2k1: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 39}, -Mcx8-SsUNEXKDr9JwX8: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 38}, -Mcx8TvgbNRO_Im5BEIv: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 38}, -Mcx6yF5lxBhJwI_oR0n: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 38}, -Mcx94EY0H7PhHsaihfd: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 38}, -Mcx6jFx5A8RpiwslDyN: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 39}, -Mcx8aOzK88q4x_HBeFw: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 38}, -Mcx6VFGyad1i8KO1hLG: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 39}, -Mcx7swFLs5QG1lM2nrA: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 39}, -McxA0fRceADOuDCDX5I: {Temperature: 21, Humidity: 38}, -Mcx5RF48_PaUjkxVvgH: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 39}, -Mcx7CTfM2Q0mTCxykCj: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 39}, -Mcx6G1t_8m9gU1VI7Vf: {Temperature: 22, Humidity: 39}, -Mcx6bj61JAi_vWL25Hl: {Temperature: 22, Humidi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
debugPrint('Data : ${snapshot.value}')
```

instead of

```
print('Data :${snapshot.value}');
```

in the `printResults` method.

Here's an explanation from https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging#logging:

> If you output too much at once, then Android sometimes discards some
> log lines. To avoid this, use debugPrint(), from Flutter’s foundation
> library. This is a wrapper around print that throttles the output to a
> level that avoids being dropped by Android’s kernel.